# How do I execute a jQuery function on page load if and only if the page is accessed via a specific hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple link, like so:

```
<a href="page2.html">Go to Page 2</a>
```

I'd like that, when clicking this Button, it would go to the page and run a jQuery function, like so:

```
$("#object-selector div").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({borderTopColor: '#fdcc06', borderRightColor: '#fdcc06', borderBottomColor: '#fdcc06', borderLeftColor: '#fdcc06'}, 200).children().animate({backgroundColor: '#fed944', color: '#351e00'}, 200);
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).animate({borderTopColor: '#FFF', borderRightColor: '#FFF', borderBottomColor: '#FFF', borderLeftColor: '#FFF'}, 200).children().animate({backgroundColor: '#af081f', color: '#FFF'}, 200);
    }
);
```

But that function shouldn't execute if the Page is navigated to *without* clicking the link. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: So the animation only happens when you access the page through the link?

Comment: Huh? Do you want the listed code to happen, but only when the page is opened via that link and not otherwise? (It may be worth asking colleagues to help with translation.)

Comment: Yes, the Animation should Happen only when you Access the page Through the link.

Comment: I would go over your grammar again, that question was really unclear. I hope I helped, but maybe it's not what you wanted.

Comment: @KingKongFrog I suspect you're on to the actual solution; you should edit your answer to elaborate on this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a way of achieving this with PHP. By changing your href into this

```
<a href="page2.html?click=1">Go to Page 2</a>
```

and then including the following on your page:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['click']){

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "
$(\"#object-selector div\").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({borderTopColor: '#fdcc06', borderRightColor: '#fdcc06', borderBottomColor: '#fdcc06', borderLeftColor: '#fdcc06'}, 200).children().animate({backgroundColor: '#fed944', color: '#351e00'}, 200);
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).animate({borderTopColor: '#FFF', borderRightColor: '#FFF', borderBottomColor: '#FFF', borderLeftColor: '#FFF'}, 200).children().animate({backgroundColor: '#af081f', color: '#FFF'}, 200);
    }
);
";
echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

Note that this will only work on a server with PHP installed, not on your local machine.

Comment: I really Think your Answer is right, I'm Testing it, thanks alot!

Comment: Yep! You done it. It worked wonderfully! Thanks alot for that.
For understand the code, the php get the ?click, but what is the meaning of the '1' after? I mean, Can I do multiple of this links, like page2.html?click=1, page2.html?click=2 ? Thanks.

Comment: it just sets a value to $_GET['click']

Comment: Ohh, ok, Now i get it! Thanks. Sorry for the weird question and my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it all client-side, you could append a hash to your URL

```
<a href="page2.html#hover">Go to Page 2</a>
```

And then use the following code

```
<script>
if(window.location.hash === '#hover') {
    $(function() {
        $("#object-selector div").hover( ... , ... );
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: The jQuery Function is not the problem, I mean, The Animation Should happen only if you access the page through the <a> link.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine actually! +1